# Copy constructor called endlessly from lambda capture group

Tags: c++, lambda, copy-constructor

I wrote the following class to create values of any type which are either fixed or recalculated everytime the call operator is used on them:

```
template <typename T>
class DynamicValue {
    private:
    std::variant<T, std::function<T()>> getter;
    
    public:
    DynamicValue(const T& constant) : getter(constant){};
    template <typename F, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<F>>>
    DynamicValue(F&& function) : getter(function) {}
    DynamicValue(const T* pointer) : DynamicValue([pointer]() { return *pointer; }) {}
    DynamicValue(const DynamicValue& value) : getter(value.getter) {}
    DynamicValue(DynamicValue& value) : DynamicValue((const DynamicValue&) value) {}
    ~DynamicValue() {}
    T operator()() const { return getter.index() == 0 ? std::get<T>(getter) : std::get<std::function<T()>>(getter)(); }
};
```

I also wrote this function, which takes a `DynamicValue<int>` and returns another `DynamicValue<int>` which returns its value plus 1:

```
DynamicValue<int> plus1(DynamicValue<int> a) {
    return [a] { return a() + 1; };
}
```

However, when I attempt to do use it, the program crashes:

```
DynamicValue<int> a = 1;
DynamicValue<int> b = plus1(a);
```

You can try a live example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/97hbMh).

After some testing, I think the problem lies in the copy constructor, which is being called endlessly, but I'm not sure how to fix it. How can I avoid this behavior?

Comment: Did you mean to write  `DynamicValue<int> plus1(DynamicValue<int>& a) {`? Can we close this quesiton as _caused by a typo_?

Comment: `DynamicValue(DynamicValue& value)` you don't need this overload. The idiomatic const one will suffice. Actually you don't need any copy ctor. Follow the rule of zero.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I did not mean to write that, and it made no difference when I tried it.

Comment: @bolov I added that overload as a temporary fix for another bug I had encountered. Either way, removing the copy ctor made no difference in this case.

Comment: I think your c'tor template is problematic. It would be the best match for `DynamicValue` rvalues. On account of the class itself being invocable.

Comment: *"removing the copy ctor made no difference in this case."* -- please continue down this path. Remove all the code that is not needed to reproduce the error, c.f. [mre].

Comment: @JaMiT Actually, nevermind, it made a difference. Without the constructor and its overload, `DynamicValue<int> b = a;` also crashes the program.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica can you elaborate? I'm still quite new to C++, don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some important pieces of this code:

- A lambda captures a `DynamicValue` object by value (copy).
- The lambda is used to initialize a `std::variant` as a `std::function` alternative.
- There is no explicit move constructor for `DynamicValue`, so the template for invocable objects is used as the move constructor.

The problematic code path starts with the request to construct a `DynamicValue` object from the lambda. This invokes the template constructor, which attempts to copy the lambda into the `std::function` alternative of the `variant`. So far, so good. Copying **(not moving)** the lambda copies the captured object without problems.

However, this procedure works when the [CopyConstructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyConstructible) named requirement is satisfied. Part of this named requirement is being [MoveConstructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveConstructible). In order for a lambda to satisfy MoveConstructible, all of its captures have to satisfy that named requirement. Is this the case for `DynamicValue`? What happens when your standard library tries to *move* the lambda (hence also the captured object), with copying as the fallback? While `DynamicValue` has no explicit move constructor, it is invocable...

When `F` is `DynamicValue<T>`, the template constructor serves as the move constructor. It tries to initialize the `variant` by converting the source `DynamicValue` (the captured copy of `a` in the question's code) into a `std::function`. This is allowed, a copy of the source is made, and the process continues until the copy needs to be moved, at which point the move constructor is again invoked. This time, it tries to initialize the `variant` by converting the copy of the source `DynamicValue` into a `std::function`. This is allowed, a copy of the copy of the source is made, and the process continues until the copy of the copy needs to be moved, at which point the move constructor is again invoked. Etc.

Instead of moving the `DynamicValue` into the new object, each "move constructor" tries to move the `DynamicValue` into *the `variant` of* the new object. This would add another layer of overhead with each move, except the recursive calls blow up before construction finishes.

---

The solution is to make `DynamicValue` move constructible. There are at least two ways to do this.

**1)** Explicitly provide a move constructor.

```cpp
    DynamicValue(DynamicValue&& value) : getter(std::move(value.getter)) {}
```

**2)** Exclude `DynamicValue` from being a template argument to the template constructor.

```cpp
    template <typename F, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<F>>,
                          typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<F>, DynamicValue>>>
    DynamicValue(F&& function) : getter(function) {}
```

Note that this excludes only `DynamicValue<T>` from being a template argument, not `DynamicValue<U>` when `U` is not `T`. That might be another issue to contemplate.

You might want to see if this also fixes whatever problem led you to define a second copy constructor. That may have been a band-aid approach that did not address this underlying issue.

Comment: As a begginer to C++, I thank you so much for the detailed explanation. This is part of a uni project that I decided to complexify to gain extra points and learn more advanced C++ along the way. With the deadline approaching, that decision has come to bite me :) You have no idea of the headache you saved me!